# Bug - Chrome XP HTML Anchor Attribute href mailto: Weird Icons

Tags: html, google-chrome, windows-xp, href, mailto

A client sent me this screenshot of this weird bug in Chrome XP (not sure which version.) These email icons are appearing in the background or inline. I'm not sure where they are coming from. I don't even know where to start with this one. Any suggestions?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g972f3g05ibwsuo/website%20email.jpg

Comment: Did you check the styles? Inspect the element.

Comment: Also it could be some kind of browser plugin. I've had some clients in the past complaining about a blue icon next to every phone number on their sites. It was the Skype plugin installed.

Comment: It's on the client's home computer. I have not experienced this on my Chrome XP environment. A coworker suggested something similar.

Comment: If you don't have 'personal' access to their PC, the only way will be to ask them to inspect the element CSS, or you could go for a remote assistance and check it for yourself.

Comment: I found an answer to this. It did require some replicating of the user's browser experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug caused by an email/browser plugin application called Tout. Once I was able to install the application, I was able to see that the bug was caused by style rule the browser application's injected icon was inheriting.

Lesson learned from this is that child selectors can cause problems on unknown environments with injected browser applications.

This was a client specific browser issue.